# Faraday request to receive an audio blob

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, blob

I have a React frontend with a Ruby on Rails backend. I'm using a 3rd party API that converts text to voice. You submit the text and it sends you back an audio file.

I can make it work on the frontend this way:

```
const handleClick = () => {
    axios.post('theUrlForThePost', {
        text: 'Test Message',
        voice_settings: {
          stability: 0.5,
          similarity_boost: 1
        }
      },
    {
        headers: {
            'accept': 'audio/mpeg',
            'xi-api-key': `<<HIDDEN>>`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        responseType: 'blob'
    })
    .then(response => {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
        const audio = new Audio(url);
        audio.play();
        console.log('audio played')
      })
   .catch(error => {
     console.log(error);
   });
}
```

However, I like having the request happen on the backend in order to keep my API key safe. So instead on the frontend I want to:

```
axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/voice-api-proxy`)
    .then(response => {
    //. . .
    }
```

However, I can't seem to properly configure the Faraday POST request on the backend (it gets triggered via the post request to /voice-api-proxy).

This is my current attempt:

```
conn = Faraday.new(
            url: 'theBaseURLOfThePost',
            headers: { 
                'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
                'xi-api-key': api_key,
                'Accept': 'audio/mpeg',
            }
        ) do |faraday|
            faraday.use Faraday::Response::RaiseError, raise_error: false
            faraday.response :detect_content_type
            faraday.response :logger
            faraday.response :json, content_type: /\bjson$/
            faraday.response :xml, content_type: /\bxml$/
            faraday.response :blob, content_type: %r{\b(audio|video|image)/.*\b}
            faraday.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
        end
            
        response = conn.post('thePostPathOfTheURL') do |req|
            req.body = {
                text: 'Test Message',
                voice_settings: {
                    stability: 0.5,
                    similarity_boost: 1
                }
            }.to_json
        end
        
        if response.success?
            send_data response.body, type: 'audio/mpeg', disposition: 'inline'
          else
            render json: { error: 'Error occurred' }, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
        
        rescue Faraday::Error => e
          render json: { error: e.message }, status: :unprocessable_entity
```

I know there are some excess configurations here because I was playing around with some different options... please feel free to disregard all of that.

Again, my main goal is simply to return the same kind of response that my successful frontend request did.

I think the issue has to do with how to set up Faraday to handle blobs...

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I could also use **responseType: 'blob'** for my API proxy call...

Here is the backend

```
def proxy
       conn = Faraday.new(url: "theUrlForThePost") do |faraday|
            faraday.headers["accept"] = "audio/mpeg"
            faraday.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
            faraday.headers["xi-api-key"] = api_key
        end
          
          response = conn.post do |req|
            req.body = {
              text: 'Test Message',
              voice_settings: {
                stability: 0.5,
                similarity_boost: 1
              }
            }.to_json
          end
          
        render json: response.body
end
```

Frontend:

```
const proxyPost = () => {
    axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/voice-api-proxy`, {
        // request body
    }, {
    responseType: 'blob'
    }).then(response => {
        const binaryData = response.data
        const blob = new Blob([binaryData], { type: 'audio/mpeg' });
        const audioURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const audio = new Audio(audioURL);
        audio.play(); 
    })
   .catch(error => {
     console.log(error);
   });
}
```